# Is it possible to unhash sha256 if you are given the sha256 and unhash of a variable?

Tags: hash, sha-256

Lets say that $a, b, c$ are variables and you know that

$$\operatorname{sha256}(a) = b \\
\operatorname{decrypt}(b) = a \\ \operatorname{sha256}(b) = c \\ \operatorname{decrypt}(c) = b$$

Is it possible to find $a$?

Comment: What do you mean by decrypt ?

Comment: Do you know the value of b, and c?

Answer (score 1):

Nope!

First, for sufficiently long inputs, knowledge of sha256(a) doesn't uniquely determine a: there exist two distinct 257-bit strings x and y such that sha256(x) = sha256(y).  (Proof: There are only $2^{256}$ distinct *values* that sha256(x) can take on, so if you enumerate $2^{256} + 1$ values of x, one of the values of sha256(x) will be repeated.)  From what you described, either x or y could be the result of decrypt(sha256(x)) or decrypt(sha256(y)).

Second, sha256 is conjectured to be **preimage-resistant**: the best algorithms that we know which when given h find some x such that sha256(x) = h with high probability take more energy than all of humanity has available to spend.  Even if you had such an algorithm, it's unlikely that the x found by such an algorithm would bear any resemblance to the input you fed to sha256; most likely x would look like 512 or 1024 bits of garbage.